# ReminderMe function Using LoginPage in asp .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have used these methods in AccountController.cs:

```
public ActionResult DomainLogin(string returnUrl)
{
} 

public string Loginss(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
}
```

My problem is I have redirect method to index page after login. Trying to copy URL `Home/Index` after closing and reopening the browser again with pasted URL, I get redirected to `Account/Login` page and `public ActionResult DomainLogin(string returnUrl) {}` is called when browser closed.

Here is RouteConfig.cs code:

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            if (ctx.Session == null)
            {
                routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
        else
        {
            if (ctx.Session != null)
            {
              if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
                {
                    string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                    //if ((sessionCookie != null) || (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                        if (sessionCookie != null)
                {
                        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
                        routes.MapRoute(
                            name: "Home_Default",
                            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                        );

                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new AjaxErrorHandlerAttribute());
        new Bootstrap().Configure(filePathToPoints:
        string.Concat(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~"), @"App_Data\Points.csv"));
    }
    static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["usernames"] != null)
        {
            string user = (string)Session["usernames"];
            UsersContext userDetails = new UsersContext();
            UserProfile data = userDetails.UserProfiles.Where(m => m.UserName == user).FirstOrDefault();
            if (data != null)
            {
                data.Preference = "NoLog";
                data.Logged = false;
            }
            userDetails.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use cookie.

Comment: yes, i have used cookie on myproject. i have use for   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

Comment: sorry for written incorrect english